# How to best translate the IT term "technical debt"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

In the computer science/programming world, what would be the best way to translate "technical debt"?

The concept is described [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) as:

> *Technical debt* (also known as *design debt* or *code debt*) is a concept in software development that reflects the implied cost of additional rework caused by choosing an easy solution now instead of using a better approach that would take longer.

*"Deuda técnica"* sounds a bit too literal for my taste, but some other opinions/ideas/suggestions would be very welcome. Is *"deuda técnica"* the best way to communicate that idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the literal translation **deuda técnica** fits perfectly.

Being an IT professional, I didn't know the term, but after reading [this definition](https://www.scrum.org/resources/blog/product-backlog-and-technical-debt), I can say that I've experienced it more than once.

> **Technical debt** can be defined as the longer term consequences of **poor design** decisions

You have to take into account that in software development there is a phase named **technical design** which is usually translated as **diseño técnico** (with its namesake documents) and which seems to be the origin of this **technical debt**

I disagree with @walen, I think that **tecnológica** is not a adequate in this context.

Let's check the D.R.A.E

[tecnológica](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZJ48HuC)

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la tecnología.

[tecnología](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZJ2KRZZ)

> 1. f. Conjunto de teorías y de técnicas que permiten el aprovechamiento práctico del conocimiento científico.

[técnica](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZIkyMDs)

> 5. f. Conjunto de procedimientos y recursos de que se sirve una ciencia o un arte.
> 6. f. **Pericia o habilidad para usar una técnica**.

As you can see, tecnología and técnica may be synonimous. But in IT usually a tecnology identifies a programming language or a bunch of libraries and the tecnical debt is not directly related with that, I think that it has got more to do with how you employ such technology, how you design a solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitively 'deuda técnica', as you can check in different technical works, for example [here](https://www.enriquedans.com/2017/06/entendiendo-el-concepto-de-deuda-tecnica.html) or [here](https://www.scrummanager.net/bok/index.php?title=Deuda_t%C3%A9cnica). It is true that normally these technical or business concepts are not translated, and we use the English term, as in *briefing*, *portfolio*, *scrum manager*, etc., but others are translated, as in this case.

[Here](https://www.eldiario.es/hojaderouter/tecnologia/diccionario-tecnologia-RAE-DRAE-terminos-palabras_0_317768422.html) you can read a good article about the adoption of technological words by RAE.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta, indicando casos donde se utiliza!

Answer (score 2):

I think *"deuda técnica"* works OK; however, it's true that in Spanish *"técnica"* is used in a way that is not always associated with technology: *[falta técnica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falta_t%C3%A9cnica), [parada o escala técnica](https://dle.rae.es/?id=G67txjD#6UZEsoO)*...  In these examples, *"técnica"* means something like "mandated by the rules".
If you want to avoid this meaning, you can use *"**deuda tecnológica**"* instead, which makes it even more clear — while still being close enough to the original (for a non-native to understand you, I mean).